# VLookup A Value from another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table layout. I am looking for a formula to look up between the two tables using IDNUMBER (Column H an L) and then print the income Value(Column S) for inside of (Column L "Column1").

[image]

See reference above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your column L then should have the formula in row 2:

```
=VLOOKUP(H2,R:S,2,False)
```

then just drag it down to the rest of the rows